# Bind featherlight to modal content but without also opening the modal

Tags: featherlight.js

Is it possible to bind/setup/init featherlight without also opening the modal?

Currently `var modal = $.featherlight($target,config)` binds and then opens.

I have worked around it for now by immediately invoking `modal.close()` but this feels hacky.

Possible options:

*1) New config option openOnBind (true/false)*

*2) Bind should not open by default - user can choose to use .open() afterwards as needed.*

I have also tried `var modal = $target.featherlight(config)` but
both `$target.open()` and `modal.open()` then fail - neither contain the featherlight object/instance.

Where is the featherlight instance hiding? :)

Fiddled:
http://jsfiddle.net/eybb104r/2/

P.S. The context for this is launching a modal based on the presence of a cookie, so I need to bind a modal without a DOM element trigger.

Comment: I first misunderstood what you meant by "*bind*". I thought you meant to bind a featherlight to a dom element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really unclear *why* you want to do this, as there aren't any useful methods to call on a closed featherlight.

It's not documented (nor really supported), but you can do:

```
var fl = new $.Featherlight($content, config);
// Do something here, really unclear what though
fl.open();
```

Comment: Thanks - the context is that the modal is being launched depending on the presence of a certain browser cookie.

Comment: Is there a more logical way you would see Featherlight achieving this? Example context: http://jsfiddle.net/me12Ltaj/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yun8ospq/ or create yourself a function that calls featherlight, and call that function within your `if`